# Installing teleport tsh cause ssh to fail due to trying too many keys

Tags: ssh, teleport

After installing tsh, my ssh and `git pull` stopped working. The error message says:

> too many authentication failures

Inspecting ssh with  -v flag I see that it is trying teleport specific keys first, and there are many of them:

```
debug1: get_agent_identities: bound agent to hostkey
debug1: get_agent_identities: agent returned 8 keys
debug1: Will attempt key: teleport:me@example.com RSA-CERT SHA256: agent
debug1: Will attempt key: teleport:me@example.com RSA SHA256: agent
debug1: Will attempt key: teleport:teleport.example.net:gstg-teleport-group:me@example.com RSA-CERT SHA256: agent
debug1: Will attempt key: teleport:teleport.example.net:gstg-teleport-group:me@example.com RSA SHA256: agent
debug1: Will attempt key: teleport:staging.teleport.example.net:staging.teleport.example.net:me@example.com RSA-CERT SHA256: agent
debug1: Will attempt key: teleport:staging.teleport.example.net:staging.teleport.example.net:me@example.com RSA SHA256: agent
debug1: Will attempt key: teleport:production.teleport.example.net:production.teleport.example.net:me@example.com RSA-CERT SHA256: agent
debug1: Will attempt key: teleport:production.teleport.example.net:production.teleport.example.net:me@example.com RSA SHA256: agent
debug1: Will attempt key: /Users/me/.ssh/id_rsa RSA SHA256:
```

What would be a good way to fix this?

Answer (score 1):

tsh is adding too many keys to local SSH agent.

`ssh-add -D` would remove currently stored keys in the agent.

[Set TELEPORT_USE_LOCAL_SSH_AGENT to false](https://goteleport.com/docs/connect-your-client/tsh/#ssh-agent-support) would mean they won't be added into the agent in the future.